# Postgres column timestamp is of type timestamp but expression is of type text

Tags: c#, postgresql

I just started working with PostgreSQL for a timeseries database using timescale. Before i use timescale i wanted to setup a little test for inserting data.
Whilest inserting data from c# into a postgres database table i run into the following error:

```
column "timestamp" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text
```

I was looking trough the documentation of postgres but couldnt find the solution.

this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE measurement_ms (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    value VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP(6) NULL,
    machine_id INT NOT NULL,
    measurement_type_id INT NOT NULL,
    point_of_measurement_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (machine_id) REFERENCES machine (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (measurement_type_id) REFERENCES measurement_type (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (point_of_measurement_id) REFERENCES point_of_measurement (id)
);
```

and this is the code in c# i'm using to insert the data into the table:

```
 NpgsqlCommand addMeasurementQuery = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO measurement_ms (value, timestamp, machine_id, measurement_type_id, point_of_measurement_id) values(@value, @timestamp, @machine_id, @measurement_type_id, @point_of_measurement_id)", connection);
            addMeasurementQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value);
            addMeasurementQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestamp", timestamp.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:MS"));
            addMeasurementQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machine_id", fk_machineID);
            addMeasurementQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@measurement_type_id", fk_pointOfMeasurementID);
            addMeasurementQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@point_of_measurement_id", fk_measurementTypeID);
            addMeasurementQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Can someone give a push into the right direction to solve this issue? I think i might format the timestamp incorrect but im not sure.

Comment: Since your using npgsql, your varable has to be DateTime here is more info: [npgsql datetime](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research about this issue i found the following solution:
I tried what Dan said in the comments but couldnt get it to work.

```
NpgsqlCommand addMeasurementQuery = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO verbruggen_iot.measurement_ms (value, timestamp, machine_id, measurement_type_id, point_of_measurement_id) values(@value, CAST(@timestamp as timestamp), @machine_id, @measurement_type_id, @point_of_measurement_id)", connection);
```

The difference between the query in the question and this one is that i cast the timestamp the following way:

`CAST(@timestamp as timestamp)`

Using the cast above i'm stil able to execute the rest of my code.